# How do you draw a line dynamically in vb6?

Tags: vb6, dynamic, line

I'm trying to get data from a database in order to draw a line on a vb6 form. I was looking at [this site](http://www.bitwisemag.com/copy/vb/vb_graphics1.html), but I'm not even a beginner in vb6, and I really couldn't follow it.

If anyone has any suggestion, even if it's just about drawing a line in vb6 (not dynamically), I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: One straight line, or many lines, or a compound line, or a curve, or...?

Look into the GDI line drawing functions. Start with MoveTo and LineTo, then ArcTo and PolyLine for more complex drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you dynamically draw a line:

```
    Me.Line (x1, y1)-(x2, y2)
```

Basically, this allows to to draw a straight line from one co-ordinate to another; for example:

```
    Me.Line (10, 10)-(1000, 1000)
```

You could just replace these values with values from the DB.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing.