# How to draw in a picturebox in vb6

Tags: vb6, drawing, picturebox

i have used loads of websites for this but none worked so i am hoping i could get a correct answer

i have tried this could any one tell me whats wrong with it:

```
    Private sub Picture1_mouseDown
    x = picture1.currentx
    y = picture1.currenty
    End sub

    Private sub Picture1_MouseMove
    If button = 1 then
    line (picture1.currentx,picture1.currenty)-(x,y), _
    QBColor(0)
    End if 
    End sub
```

i have cut the Private sub Picture1_MouseMove,Mousedown() bits off because i am in a rush to finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one will draw a line, only slightly different from kurniliya's solution which draws points

```
Option Explicit

Private lastX As Single
Private lastY As Single

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' no need to set this every time we move the mouse inside Picture1
    Picture1.DrawWidth = 5
End Sub

Private Sub Picture1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = 1 Then
        Picture1.Line (lastX, lastY)-(X, Y), vbBlue
    End If
    lastX = X
    lastY = Y
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You draw a line on `PictureBox` control using its `Line` method:

> Sub Line(Flags As Integer, X1 As Single, Y1 As Single, X2 As Single, Y2 As Single, Color As Long)
>
> ```
> Member of VB.PictureBox
> Draws lines and rectangles on an object.
> ```

There isn't much to say about it, and it has already been covered in [How do you draw a line dynamically in vb6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088761/how-do-you-draw-a-line-dynamically-in-vb6)

You seem to have trouble with writing event handlers though. If you don't know/remember the signature, IDE is always there to assist. Check out [Assigning Code to a Control to Respond to an Event in VB6](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson3/p21.html) tutorial.

There is the code to help you get started with drawing. `Picture1` is `PictureBox` control. Blue line will be drawn when you move your mouse over the picture box holding left mouse button down.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Picture1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    If Button = 1 Then
        Picture1.DrawWidth = 5
        Picture1.Line (X, Y)-(X, Y), vbBlue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Swynco.Inc, `Option Explicit` is probably the most important thing for you to take away from this answer for all your future coding in VB6

Comment: this works - to a degree. It doesn't draw a line, rather a point, and is pretty much analogous to `Picture1.PSet (X, Y)` with added control over point color. @Swynco.Inc was going in the direction of drawing lines - or at least connected points, as you can see from the `MouseMove` handler. Try this code while moving the mouse quickly and you will see that it is drawing points, not lines.